# TreeForm and Unevaluated

Tags: bugs, evaluation, output, attributes

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and persisting through 12.0 or later**

---

Check this example:

```
Attributes[Unevaluated]
(*{HoldAllComplete, Protected}*)
FullForm[Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]]
(*Unevaluated[List[List[Plus[5, 6]], List[Plus[7, 8]]]]*)
```

now:

```
TreeForm[Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]]
```

[image]

```
expr = Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]

(*{{11}, {15}}*)
```

**Note here the result is like `Unevaluated` is not applied at all.**

It looks like (according to the documentation also) that `Unevaluated` uses its Attributes ONLY once.

When compared with `HoldComplete`, which has same `Attributes`, the results are different and as expected.

**in the case of `HoldComplete`:**

```
FullForm[HoldComplete[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]]
(*HoldComplete[List[List[Plus[5, 6]], List[Plus[7, 8]]]]*)
TreeForm[HoldComplete[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]]
```

[image]

It is clear that the `TreeForm` does not represent the `FullForm` when using `Unevaluated` and works perfectly in the case of `HoldComplete`.

How does that happen with `Unevaluated`?

Comment: @kuba, you can see that the TreeFrom does not represent the FullForm. the TreeForm is like Unevaluated is not applied at all. Furthermore the result of expr = Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}] is also like Unevaluated  is not applied. I will try to edit the equation now.

Comment: Relevant StackOverflow thread: "[Why does `TreeForm[Unevaluated[4^5]]` evaluate the `4^5`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5722679/590388)"

Comment: Related: [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25727/280), [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6552/280).

Comment: I'd say `Unevaluated` is underdocumented. But I do not see a bug here. Internals of function implementations are allowed to strip `Unevaluated` and presumably `TreeForm` is doing just that.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau "Internals of function implementations are allowed to strip `Unevaluated`" - Isn't this called *evaluation leak*?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau There is an old discussion of this issue on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722679/mathematica-why-does-treeformunevaluated45-evaluate-the-45#comment6551856_5723277

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Actually `Unevaluated` is sufficiently well documented for such a basic use cases: apart from `ref/Unevaluated` there is also `tutorial/Evaluation` which adds significant information. The example on `ref/Unevaluated` `Length[Unevaluated[5 + 6 + 7 + 8]]` correctly gives `4` what demonstrates the expected behavior of `Unevaluated`. If `Length`'s internals would be allowed to evaluate the expression, the `Unevaluated` would be just pointless.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Hence the expected behavior is that `Unevaluated` should be stripped by the evaluator which must temporarily set the `HoldAllComplete` attribute to `TreeForm`. Then the unevaluated expression should be processed by `TreeForm`'s internals without evaluating it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you observe is a bug (evaluation leak) inside of `TreeForm`. In particular, observe this:

```
TreeForm[Unevaluated[Print[5 + 6]]]
```

> ```
> 11
> 11
> ```

As you see, `Print` is evaluated twice inside of the `TreeForm` code. It is apparent bug and I suggest you to report it to technical support.

Note that in *Mathematica* 5.2 `TreeForm` doesn't have the evaluation leak:

[image]

There is no leak in the terminal interface in newer versions too:

[image]

From this comes a workaround - just wrap `TreeForm` with `OutputForm`:

```
TreeForm[Unevaluated[Print[5 + 6]]] // OutputForm
```

[image]

Note that this behavior is still not completely in accord with the Documentation for `Unevaluated`: since `TreeForm` doesn't have the `HoldAllComplete` attribute, the `Unevaluated` wrapper should be **stripped off** on the first stage of the evaluation process temporarily setting this attribute to `TreeForm` (refs: "Details" section on [ref/Unevaluated](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) and the fourth bullet point under the "[The Standard Evaluation Sequence](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html#19212)").

Also `TreeForm` displays strings without quotes by default what makes it difficult to separate them from `Symbol`s. But on the base of this feature we can easily make the correct `treeForm` by converting all the `Symbol`s and `String`s into `InputForm` strings:

```
treeForm[expr_, opts___] := 
 TreeForm[Unevaluated[
    expr] /. {s : (_Symbol | _String) :> ToString[Unevaluated[s], InputForm]}, opts]

treeForm[Unevaluated[Print[5 + 6 + "string"]], ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> .4]
```

[image: screenshot]

But it still requires additional work to make it working correctly with `Image` and probably some other atomic objects.

Comment: Alexey Pokov, sorry for late reply. I think the problem is with Unevaluated not TreeForm. check expr = Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}] you will see that this will evaluate Unevaluated argument.

Comment: The expected behavior of `TreeForm` should be as in this example: `treeForm@Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]` (it is the documented behavior). Your example is principally different and actually is a special case (undocumented).

Comment: I don't think it is a special case. Unevaluated evaluate its argument whenever some other operation are carried out. for example: Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]*1 or Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}] + 0. Still something not clear about the behavior of Unevaluated when other functions are used like List[Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]]

Comment: What your call "unclear" is the expected behavior. The cases like `Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]*1` can be understood from `Trace[Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]*1, TraceOriginal -> True]`. What happens is that at the first step the `Unevaluated` is stripped off and without evaluation of its contents (as expected) and you get `{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}*1`. Now further evaluation rules (built-in) of `Times` are applied, consider this hand-made reconstruction of `Times`: `times[x__] := times2[x]; Trace[
 times[1, Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]], TraceOriginal -> True]`. (continued)

Comment: As you see, at the second step you have a new expression without `Unevaluated` which is evaluated in the usual way. Now check this: `SetAttributes[times2, HoldAll];times[x__] := times2[x]; Trace[times[1, Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]], TraceOriginal -> True]`. You see that if `times2` has the `HoldAll` attribute you get almost the same result as without any evaluation rules defined: evaluation stops but in any case `Unevaluated` fires when the first evaluation rule fires.

Comment: In the other words, `Unevaluated` is already stripped off at the first step when the first evaluation rule was applied. But what will happen if the evaluation rule must not be applied? Consider this: `Clear[times];
times[x__]:=times2[x]/;False;Trace[times[1,Unevaluated[{{5+6},{7+8}}]],TraceOriginal->True]`. You see that at some step the `Unevaluated` is stripped off but finally the original expression is returned. In other words, if the evaluation does not change the original expression, `Unevaluated` is not stripped off in the result.

Comment: very clear. it is indeed an "(evaluation leek) inside of TreeForm". Even Trace[TreeForm[Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]],TraceOriginal -> True] can not capture the process how TreeForm works. The first element is indeed the final result of TreeForm[Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]]. The case is similar with Trace[FullForm[Unevaluated[{{5 + 6}, {7 + 8}}]],TraceOriginal -> True], however FullForm holds perfectly its argument unevaluated whereas TreeFrom is not. Thanks a lot:)